# How to make tkinter widgets automatically resize when the root window is resized?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am designing a simple GUI and I am having trouble getting the two tkinter widgets, the Text and the Entry widget to automatically resize when the tkinter window is resized. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

> Code:

```
from tkinter import *

# *** Create Window ***
root = Tk()

# *** GUI ***
chatSpace = Text(root, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=2)
chatSpace.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E)

input_box = Entry(root, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=2)
input_box.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10, padx=10, sticky=W+E)

root.mainloop()
```

> Problem:

[image: Problem]

> Desired outcome:
>   I would like the two widgets to automatically resize when the window is resized. Thank you!

Comment: There are _many_ questions on this site related to using `grid` and having widgets expand to fill empty space. Have you done any research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need to do is add these two lines of code under root = Tk().

```
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```